# Project structure for large Angular application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am new to angular js

I want to create my project structure like this

```
- APPLICATION
  -index.html
  -app.js
  -modules
     -core
       -controllers
       -directive
       -views
       -core.app.js
       -core.config.routes.js

     -test
       -controllers
       -directive
       -views
       -test.app.js
       -test.config.routes.js
```

Here core, test is different modules(ng-app)

I configure like Here

**app.js**
  angular.module('mainapp',['mainapp.core','mainapp.test'])

**core.app.js**
  angular.module('mainapp.core',[])

**test.app.js**
  angular.module('mainapp.test',[])

Here I am gettiing problem that my core module states are not working properly . I am using $staeprovider(ui-views) for routing.

example

**core.config.routes.js**

```
angular.module('mainapp.core').config(function($stateProvider,
        $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
    .state('core', {
      url: '/core',
      templateUrl: 'modules/core/views/core.html',

    })
    .state('core.sidebar ', {
      url: '^/sidebar ',
      templateUrl: 'modules/core/views/core.sidebar .html'
    })
     });
```

**test.config.routes.js**

```
angular.module('mainapp.test').config(function($stateProvider,
        $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider

    .state('core.sidebar .test', {
      url: '^/test',
      templateUrl: 'modules/core/views/test.html'
    })
     });
```

my html pages are

**index.html**

```
  <div ng-app="mainapp">
      <div ui-view= ""></div>
   </div>
```

**core.html**

```
  `    <div>
           <h1>I am designing jeader Here. it goes on tp of page</h1>
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div>`
```

**core.sidebar .html**

```
    `<div>
     <h2>It goes left side</h2>

      <h1>I am designing sidebar Here</h1>

      <div ui-view></div>
     </div>`
```

till Here it's working fine. heaser, sider bar is loading $state at **core.sidebar**

Here I am getting problem it' not working
  **test.html**

```
 <div>
      <h1>I am designing middle content Here</h1>

   </div>
```

Please any one help me to solve the issue and build better approach for project structure

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look at the Angular Style Guide in how they recommend project structuring.  https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#application-structure-lift-principle

I really like their recommendation for using the LIFT approach:

> - Locating our code is easy
> - Identify code at a glance
> - Flat structure as long as we can
> - Try to stay DRY (Don’t Repeat Yourself) or T-DRY

In that spirit, you might just have a modules folder and then use a file naming convention to keep things organized.  On my projects, I do this and use ng-structure prefixes.  Example:

- nx.core

  - controller.header
  - controller.footer
  - controller.app
  - routes
- nx.admin

  - routes
  - controller.admin
  - directive.blah

Doing this, I was able to achieve both the flat organization as well as a quickly filtering by eye, what files I need.  Then only drawback is if you use a shortcut in your IDE to quickly open files, you normally think in terms of *FindingsController* not via a prefix like *controller.Findings*.

Just my 2¢